# How to give Material Button ShapeAppearance seperate to Edittext Shape Appearance?

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android, material-components, android-shapedrawable

In android, you could setup a theme with `ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent` so if I set,

```
<style name="Some.Theme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.MyShape.SmallComponent</item>
    ...
</style>
```

If I defined `ShapeAppearance.MyShape.SmallComponent` to be rounded as so:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearance.MyShape.SmallComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">@dimen/someDPValue</item>
</style>
```

I could get my `MaterialButton` to a rounded shape.

My problem is that this also affects the `shapeAppearance` of all of my `Edittext` which is not what I want.

Is it possible to provide a different `shapeAppearance` for `Button` and a different one for `Edittext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the component's shape by overriding the style of the component and defining a custom **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`**.

For example for the MaterialButton you can use the **`materialButtonStyle`** attribute in the app theme:

```
<style name="Some.Theme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/MyApp.Button</item>
</style>
```

where:

```
<style name="MyApp.Button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
   <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.MaterialButton</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.MaterialButton" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">@dimen/...</item>
</style>
```